# I can't change mode for some directories using chmod

Tags: command-line, permissions, virtualization, tty, chmod

For some reason I can't change the file mode for some directories:

[image: click here to see Screenshots]

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User joe is the owner of the directory `joe` so only joe or root can run `chmod` on it. You will have to use `sudo`

```
sudo chmod o-x joe
```